# I keep getting SQLError using sql request built part by part

Tags: java, mysql

I have a JavaFX App where the user inputs some informations about him and then I have a class that is named `DbUpdateBuilder`that allows me to create my sql resquest more easily. And then I use `statement.executeUpdate(request)`

The issue is that I always get this error :
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: syntax error near " line 1` So I thought something was wrong my request so I printed the request I got :

```
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`first_name`=null,`users`.`last_name`=null,`users`.`age`=null,`users`.`role`=null,`users`.`gender`= 3  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 10
```

which works if I hard code it.

this do not work

```
            // Some code
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String request = builder.getRequest();
            System.out.println(request); // where the request in the 
                                         // working exemple comes from

            if(stmt.executeUpdate(request) > 0) { // I get the error from this 
                                                  // line
                return UPDATE_SUCCESS;
            }
            return SQL_ERROR_OCCURED;
```

but this do work

```
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String request = builder.getRequest();
            System.out.println(request);
            if(stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`first_name`=null,`users`.`last_name`=null,`users`.`age`=null,`users`.`role`=null,`users`.`gender`= 3  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 10") > 0) {
                return UPDATE_SUCCESS;
            }
            return SQL_ERROR_OCCURED;
```

I must precize that the request hard coded in the working example comes from a copy & paste of the request printed in the not working example

Comment: In prepared statements you mustn't use data within the query. Use parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion 
LIKE work on string  and normally is used  with wild char

could be you need
if you need  exact  match  then use equal

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `users`.`first_name`=null,
    `users`.`last_name`=null,
    `users`.`age`=null,
    `users`.`role`=null,
    `users`.`gender`= 3  
WHERE `users`.`id` = 10
```

if you need  a pattern match the use like and wildchar eg;

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `users`.`first_name`=null,
    `users`.`last_name`=null,
    `users`.`age`=null,
    `users`.`role`=null,
    `users`.`gender`= 3  
WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE '%10%'
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced `users`.`id` LIKE 10 by `users`.`id` = 10. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion @scaisEdge. But I found the issue on my own : I compared the two strings (the one hard coded and the one generated by my builder) they had the same lenght so I printed char by char each string and then I found the issue ! some chars were equal to null so SQL didn't like it and generated error but when I printed it null chars were ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes quotes ' are not acceptable by mysql but you can try this as simple with no qoutes

```
  UPDATE users 
     SET first_name=null,
       last_name=null,
       age=null,
       role=null,
       gender='3' 
  WHERE id LIKE '%10%'
```

And make sure your datatypes are correct, also null is equal to empty you can try change it to '' like first_name=''